# Only show cookie notice when a cookie is actually used

Tags: javascript, python, django

I find these cookie-notices that are needed to comply with the EU cookie-law quite annoying. The web page I'm working on are not using cookies on most of it's pages (only as CSRF-protection on some). So my idea is to only show the notice when and if a user encounter a page that actually contains a cookie.

I tried the following code in the base-template with the `django.core.context_processors.request` template context processor enabled:

```
  {% if request.COOKIES %}
  <!-- Begin Cookie Consent plugin by Silktide - http://silktide.com/cookieconsent -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/cc.silktide.com/cookieconsent.latest.min.js"></script>
  <!-- End Cookie Consent plugin -->
  {% endif %}
```

It kind of work, but it is not showing the cookie at the same page as it was set. Instead it is showing it on the first page the user is coming to after it is set (that is, the first time to request-object contains a cookie).

Is it possible to get it to display the cookie notice when the cookie is actually set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are actually set by response object, not by request. Request will only receive cookies that have been already set in client browser.

What's more, some cookies are set by middleware classes in `parse_response` method. That method is triggered after processing your view, so there is no way to retrieve that in your template. It will be assigned in `parse_response` by sessions and csrf mddlewares.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to update the Cookie Consent src to `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.9/cookieconsent.min.js`

source: [Important update to users of Cookie Consent 2.0](https://silktide.com/really-important-update-to-users-of-cookie-consent-2/)